# Create jhipster monolithic UAA application

Tags: jhipster

I'd like to generate with jHipster an UAA like application with the front end and backend in a monolithic application. I'd like to use the uaa Oauth2 server in order to connect with other application. Am i forced to generate a gateway + registry + uaa in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, in monolith all necessary oauth2 routine services will be there

Comment: Ok, so what should i choose in the generation wizard? if i choose "OAuth 2.0 / OIDC Authentication (stateful, works with Keycloak and Okta)" I need to start the keycloak Oauth2 service.

Answer (score 0):

UAA is not intended to works with monolith application, only in microservices environment.

If you want to have an SSO login with oauth2 I suggest you to generate your monolith with oauth2 option. Then you can choose between both Okta and keycloak.

JHipster provides docker-compose config to run a keycloak with docker (https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#oauth2).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try to integrate the UAA Oauth2 service code into the monolith on m own then.